# Ansible - how to use when with an or operator

Tags: ansible

My goal is to use a conditional check, on two variables, using the `or` operator in Ansible.
I've configured 2 variables:

```yaml
var1: test_var
var2: another_var
```

I'm using one a check on one variable works.

```yaml
when: "'te' in var1" # works!
```

But using two variables is always true.

```yaml
when: "'te' in var1 or var2" # True
when: "'xxx' in var1 or var2" # Also true, but I expect false
when: "'xxx' in var1" or "'xxx' in var2" # syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it.

```yaml
when: "'xxx' in var1 or 'te' in var2"
```

I had to ensure I was using proper quoting.